# Using popen("ls -la") produces strange result

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I wrote some C code for it to get the result of an "ls -la" command using popen and write the result into an C. The code looks like this:

```
unsigned int ls(char *destination, const char *username, const char *relative_path)
{
printf("LS IMP\n");
//if(!username || !relative_path) return -1; 
FILE *ls_pipe = NULL;
unsigned long ls_pipe_size = -1;

const char ls_command[] = "ls -la ";
char ls_path[255] = "/home/";   
char ls_full_command[255];

char buffer[255];
bzero(buffer, 255);

char *entries = NULL;   

bzero(ls_full_command, 255);

strcat(ls_path, username);
strcat(ls_path, relative_path);

strcat(ls_full_command, ls_command);
strcat(ls_full_command, ls_path);

printf("AFTER CATS\n");
ls_pipe = popen(ls_full_command, "r");

if(ls_pipe == NULL) return -1;

printf("Pipe ok!");

fseek(ls_pipe, 0, SEEK_END);
ls_pipe_size = ftell(ls_pipe);
rewind(ls_pipe);

printf("Filesize: %lu\n", ls_pipe_size);

int i;

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    fread(buffer, 1, 255, ls_pipe);

    printf("%s", buffer);
}

//entries = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * ls_pipe_size);
//if(entries == NULL) return -1;
printf("Entries ok!\n");

//if(ls_pipe_size != fread(destination, sizeof(char), ls_pipe_size, ls_pipe))   return -1;

fclose(ls_pipe);
return strlen(destination);

}
```

The problem is the size of the pipe is huge (?) and in the result after the proper result three entries start to appear non-stop for like infinity.

Is there any way of reading from it without knowing the exact number of lines of the result using something like another popen with wc -l?

Thanks

P.S there are some modifications in the code when i was trying to test what's going wrong and the malloc didn't work because of the insane size of the pipe.

Comment: fread does not add a null so %s is wrong.

Comment: Yes i know, this is more debugging code. The problem is I don't know where to put the '\0' because after the proper result i get garbage, so i don't know where the result end and the garbage starts.

Comment: You are not checking for the EBADF that fseek is returning.

Comment: Yep the fseek seems to not work with pipe fd's. Any idea how to extract only the needed lines/data without resorting to other sys commands and piping the result?

Comment: fread returns the amount read.  Add it up in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't seek on a pipe — period.  Any value you get back from `ftell()` is immaterial or erroneous.  You can't rewind a pipe because you can't seek on a pipe.  You can only read data once from a pipe.

So, you need to redesign the code to read an indefinite amount of data.

Here's some reasonably working code — but I needed to adapt it to Mac OS X and my machine, so instead of `/home/` it uses `/Users/`, and the call to `ls()` uses my user name.  The code properly handles buffers full of data that do not end with a null (listing about 570 lines of output for my `bin` directory).  I've left the interface to `ls` unchanged although it almost doesn't use `destination` and returning the length of `destination` is otherwise unrelated to what it is doing.  It also uses `pclose()` to close the pipe. Using `pclose()` avoids leaving zombies around and returns the exit status of the executed program where `fclose()` will not.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static unsigned int ls(char *destination, const char *username, const char *relative_path)
{
    printf("LS IMP\n");
    assert(destination != 0 && username != 0 && relative_path != 0);
    const char ls_command[] = "ls -la ";
    char ls_path[255] = "/Users/";
    char ls_full_command[255];

    snprintf(ls_full_command, sizeof(ls_full_command), "%s %s%s/%s",
             ls_command, ls_path, username, relative_path);

    FILE *ls_pipe = popen(ls_full_command, "r");

    if (ls_pipe == NULL)
        return -1;

    printf("Pipe ok!\n");

    char buffer[255];
    int nbytes;
    while ((nbytes = fread(buffer, 1, 255, ls_pipe)) > 0)
        printf("%.*s", nbytes, buffer);
    putchar('\n');

    printf("Entries ok!\n");
    pclose(ls_pipe);
    return strlen(destination);
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int length = ls("/", "jleffler", "bin");
    printf("ls() returned %u\n", length);
    return(0);
}
```